# Creating a dictionary of only the max common pairing of groups

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to create a dictionary of the max common pairings - an "agreement" table. Is it possible to shorten the code a bit when finding the agreement? As of now, I am not really liking finding the max count and then matching on the count to find the "agreement".

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'value': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]})

df = df.groupby(["id","value"]).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0: "count"})
df["max_rank"] = df.groupby(["id"])["count"].transform("max")==df["count"]
df = df.loc[(df["max_rank"]==True)]

d = defaultdict(list)

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    d[row['id']].append(row['value'])

d = [{k: v} for k, v in d.items()]

d
```

output:
[{'A': [1]}, {'B': [2]}]

Comment: What's the input if you're bypassing the pandas portion? Two lists?

Comment: Sorry I will clarify. I want to skip the group by, etc. if it's possible or at least shorten the code a bit when finding the agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a dict that maps each `id` to a list of values, and then use the `collections.Counter.most_common` method to obtain the most common value for each `id`:

```
from collections import Counter
d = {'id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'value': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]}
mapping = {}
for k, v in zip(d['id'], d['value']):
    mapping.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print({k: Counter(l).most_common(1)[0][0] for k, l in mapping.items()})
```

This outputs:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 2}
```